# DirectX 11 compatible videocards

Tags: graphics-card, directx, directx-11

My current Geforce 8800 is starting to show some weird behavior at times and I'm tempted to buy a new card. But what's the roadmap of ATI and NVidia? When are they planning to launch new videocards that are compatible with DirectX 11. I haven't heard much about them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**ATI Demonstrates “The Future” DirectX 11 Graphics Cards at Quakecon**](http://www.xbitlabs.com/news/video/display/20090814061759_ATI_Demonstrates_The_Future_DirectX_11_Graphics_Cards_at_Quakecon.html)

> “[AMD has been working hard to support DirectX 11](http://forums.amd.com/devblog/blogpost.cfm?catid=208&threadid=117048), so there are plans to make native DirectX 11 hardware from AMD in its ATI Radeon GPUs available when Windows 7 is released”.

[**AMD Set to Release DirectX 11 Graphics Card**](http://www.pcworld.com/article/169855/amd_set_to_release_directx_11_graphics_card.html)

> The release of AMD's first DirectX 11 graphics card would coincide with the launch of Microsoft's upcoming Windows 7, [AMD spokesman John Taylor]. The DirectX 11 graphics card will belong to the ATI Radeon line
>
> The graphics card maker has been demonstrating an ATI Radeon graphics card with DirectX 11 support since June, but has not made a specific product announcement yet.
>
> Microsoft's upcoming **Windows 7 has built-in support for new DirectX 11 tools**, but there is **no hardware available yet that supports those tools**. With the new card, **AMD** will beat rival **Nvidia** to market. **Nvidia** has also said it would support DirectX 11, but has not yet made a product announcement. **Intel**, which mostly offers integrated graphics on chipsets, in June released updated graphics drivers for Windows 7, but offered support for only DirectX 10.

---

Update: Active Slashdot discussion [**AMD Previews DirectX 11 Gaming Performance**](http://games.slashdot.org/story/09/08/15/1647245/AMD-Previews-DirectX-11-Gaming-Performance?from=rss)

---

Update2: **ATI Radeon HD 5870** & **HD 5850** are about to hit the market shortly.
Here is [a reference table of the DirectX 11 Radeon series](http://www.pcgameshardware.de/aid,694705/Ati-Radeon-HD-5870-und-HD-5850-Alle-Infos-und-Bilder-der-DirectX-11-Grafikkarten-Update-5-Erste-Benchmark-Werte/Grafikkarte/News/) and its street-markers (release dates) compared with the nVidia GTX 285 (the posting is in German but the table is readable).
Here is [another posting in English](http://www.pcgameshardware.com/aid,694723/Radeon-HD-5800-Details-and-pictures-of-the-DirectX-11-graphics-card-Update-New-info-and-shots/News/)...

Comment: So essentially they're still working on those video cards...

Comment: @Isxek, Yes, The Radeon card is expected to be the first one to hit the market.