# DirectX installation error

Tags: windows-7, installation, directx

Magicka started crashing on startup. While trying to fix this, I decided to update DirectX.
When I run dxwebsetup, it identifies missing "DirectX Runtime Optional Components" and attempts to install, but errors and tells me to check two log files.

Any help would be appreciated.

Error:

> An internal system error occurred. Please refer to DXError.log and
>   DirectX.log in your Windows folder to determine problem.

[DirectX.log](http://pastebin.com/LEtQ4VQm)
Too long to paste here, on pastebin instead.

[DXError.log](http://pastebin.com/nfDtLbnN):

```
--------------------
[12/28/11 13:24:59] module: dxupdate(Nov 19 2010), file: dxupdate.cpp, line: 6497, function: CMDXCheck::IsAssemblyInUse

    GetAssemblyList() failed, error = 0x80070005.

--------------------
[12/28/11 13:24:59] module: dxupdate(Nov 19 2010), file: dxupdate.cpp, line: 6497, function: CMDXCheck::IsAssemblyInUse

    GetAssemblyList() failed, error = 0x80070005.

--------------------
[12/28/11 13:24:59] module: dxupdate(Nov 19 2010), file: dxupdate.cpp, line: 6497, function: CMDXCheck::IsAssemblyInUse

    GetAssemblyList() failed, error = 0x80070005.

--------------------
[12/28/11 13:24:59] module: dxupdate(Nov 19 2010), file: dxupdate.cpp, line: 6497, function: CMDXCheck::IsAssemblyInUse

    GetAssemblyList() failed, error = 0x80070005.

--------------------
[12/28/11 13:24:59] module: dxupdate(Nov 19 2010), file: dxupdate.cpp, line: 6497, function: CMDXCheck::IsAssemblyInUse

    GetAssemblyList() failed, error = 0x80070005.

--------------------
[12/28/11 13:24:59] module: dxupdate(Nov 19 2010), file: dxupdate.cpp, line: 6497, function: CMDXCheck::IsAssemblyInUse

    GetAssemblyList() failed, error = 0x80070005.

--------------------
[12/28/11 13:24:59] module: dxupdate(Nov 19 2010), file: dxupdate.cpp, line: 6497, function: CMDXCheck::IsAssemblyInUse

    GetAssemblyList() failed, error = 0x80070005.

--------------------
[12/28/11 13:24:59] module: dxupdate(Nov 19 2010), file: dxupdate.cpp, line: 6497, function: CMDXCheck::IsAssemblyInUse

    GetAssemblyList() failed, error = 0x80070005.

--------------------
[12/28/11 13:24:59] module: dxupdate(Nov 19 2010), file: dxupdate.cpp, line: 6497, function: CMDXCheck::IsAssemblyInUse

    GetAssemblyList() failed, error = 0x80070005.

--------------------
[12/28/11 13:24:59] module: dsetup32(Mar 30 2011), file: dxupdate.cpp, line: 280, function: CSetup::InstallPlugIn

    DirectXUpdateInstallPlugIn() failed.
```

Comment: which version of DirectX? Note: Windows 7 comes preloaded with DirectX 12.

Comment: I sincerely hope that was a typo (11). I was trying to update using the [web installer](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=35)

Comment: [run --> dxdiag] and check the current DirectX version?

Comment: DirectX 11. DxDiag log here http://pastebin.com/97fTudp7

Comment: 9.0c is about 2 years old. DirectX 11 is around the most current version. And also follow [this](http://superuser.com/questions/23413/directx-11-compatible-videocards) for further information on videocards.

Comment: DirectX 11 IS the most recent version. DirectX 12 doesn't exist yet.

Comment: 0x80070005 = "Access Denied".

Comment: Any idea what might be causing it or how to enable said access?

Comment: @Ampersand: You shouldn't need to update Directx.  You should check your system files using `sfc /scannow`

Comment: Thanks surfasb. `sfc /scannow` found some corrupted files but could not repair them. What should I be looking for in the log? I searched for "error" and "fail" but only came up with some windows .wavs that I modified.

Comment: @surfasb I've had more than one game need DirectX 9C runtime bits added along side Windows 7's in-built DX.  But running an SFC is a good idea regardless. :)

Answer (score 1):

First off, try the [full DirectX 9 End-User Runtime Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8109) instead of the Web Updater.

Beyond that:

0x80070005 = "Access Denied".

Use something like [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to figure out what's it's trying to access (file, registry key, etc.) that's being denied; then examine that object to figure out why access is being denied.

Comment: Full installer also gives the same error. I will try to find what files are being accessed.

Answer (score -1):

windows 7 is a multiple user fail. u must try cmd > net user ||| net user NAME /delete and remove bs users.

after use ICACLS REPAIR to force all unowned files to you.

Comment: Be advised that asking for donations is likely to be considered spam. The offending text has been removed.